# Filter Lists for Repeats - List Deduplication

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, merge, array-merge

I have some lists of words spread across several files and I need a quick way to merge them all into one file. I'd like to remove duplicates when merging so the final list does not contain multiple instances of a single word.

**Example:**

The text file `list_a.txt` says the following:

```
apple
pear
peach
```

The text file `list_b.txt` says the following:

```
foo
bar
peach
car
```

When merged, the output file should say:

```
apple
pear
peach
foo
bar
car
```

Note that both `list_a.txt` and `list_b.txt` contained the word peach, but it only appeared once in the output file.

Here's the code I was using:

```
int main()
{
    string myList = "";
    string myFiles[] = {"list_a.txt", "list_b.txt"};
    string line;
    int iterationsSinceSleep = 0;
    size_t length = sizeof(myFiles)/sizeof(myFiles[0]);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        cout<<"Starting " << myFiles[i] << endl;
        ifstream myfile((string("C:/words/").append(myFiles[i])).c_str());
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            while ( getline (myfile,line) ){
                string trimmedLine = trim(line);
                if(myList.find(trimmedLine) == string::npos){
                    myList.append(trimmedLine + '\n');
                }

                iterationsSinceSleep++;
                iterationsSinceSleep %= 10000;
                // Save the CPU!
                if(iterationsSinceSleep == 0) Sleep(10);

            }
            myfile.close();
        }else{
            cout << "Could not open & process " << myFiles[i] << endl;
        }
        Sleep(75); // Save the CPU!
        iterationsSinceSleep = 0;
    }

    // write to the file
    ofstream myfile ("C:/words/merged/final.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"Writing filtered list"<<endl;
        myfile << myList;
        myfile.flush();
        myfile.close();
    }else{
        cout<<"Could not save filtered list."<<endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

This works fine for smaller lists/files, but one of my lists has a few million lines.

I need a way to make this code run well even if it has to process several files with millions of lines.

My first idea for improving this is to use either an array or vector instead of a string for storing the unique lines. However, both of these methods have advantages and disadvantages.

Pros of using an array:

- Faster comparison checking (I think)
- Faster element accessing

Cons of using an array:

- Reallocing to insert new strings might be slow
- The program must keep track of the array's length (not a big concern, but a factor)

Pros of using a vector:

- Dynamically add elements
- Built in searching function

Cons of using a vector:

- Inserting elements to a vector is slow (so I've read)
- I would imagine the vector has more overhead.

Can anybody offer suggestions to improve this code and write it more efficiently? Speed is a major concern, but I also need to consider memory consumption.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use an array. And if you do store it, use a data structure that won't allow dups, 2 birds 1 stone.

Comment: Hi, @ChiefTwoPencils, can you provide some reasoning and possibly an opinion of a better alternative?

Comment: I think you covered the reasoning. Resizing the array wouldn't be worth the effort/cost.

Comment: Of course, but would the cost of a vector be greater than resizing an array? Thank you for the input, by the way.

Comment: I think a trie structure would work well for this sort of thing, it may have a large memory overhead depending how you implement it but extremely fast, specially if words are very large

Comment: Well, the allocation scheme for a vector for example is better out the box. You could do the same thing by duplicating it, but then the question arises - why do that when it's already been done?

Comment: Read about the [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to get an idea of the allocation for a vector.

Comment: @MauricioTrajano, thank you for the idea, but the strings are rather short unfortunately.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, I'll read through that. I've done some reading about vectors, but hopefully something on that page can clear up some details about them.

Comment: @SpencerGrantDoak sorry I meant very short, the length of the average word determines the height of the tree, I will update my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::set`. A set does not allow duplicate entries. Try something like:

```
std::set<std::string> mySet;
...
mySet.insert(trimmedString);
...
for (auto &&str : mySet)
   myFile << str;
```

Note: I just typed this here, so may have some typos.

Also Note: this will sort the output, not sure if you want that or not.

Comment: Sorting is fine, so long as it's fast and efficient. I like the idea. I'll definitely look into the `std::set`.

Comment: The lookups are O(log n), insertion can be slow(ish) as all the objects are allocated separately, but still usually a lot faster than trying to keep an array or vector sorted. It also makes your code simpler (e.g. you can just call `insert` without needing to check if it is already in the set).

Comment: If you don't care about the order, `unordered_set` may be faster.